# Creating a blank project in eclipse or Making Intellij to auto-complete like eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I have a `java EE project` which will need some `java` coding for server side, `MySQL` coding for DB and `tomCat` for Application server and and `java Script` for client side.

I want to know how can i create a customized project in eclipse without writhing plugin for it?

Or how can I make a blank project and add these parts separately?

My favorite IDE is eclipse because of its code completion but If above things are not possible in it, can someone just tell me how can make IntelliJ IDEA to perform like eclipse completion as like as eclipse do, for example converting syso to system.out.println() :))

(i mean is there any plugin for doing this stuff on IntelliJ or I Myself should handle these things)

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ has great auto completition features. You just type `sout` and then tab and Intellij autocomplets it for you to `System.out.println()`. I recommend you to take a look at this page:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/auto-completing-code.html

But you should keep in mind that the IntelliJ Community Edition is not intended to support Java EE development. Therefore they released the Ultimate Edition.

Comment: thanks you my friend, I also find [this really usefull link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/eclipse.html) too which help me a lot. I just want to know is there a list of this kind of stuff for intellij which could help me to learn them faster?

Comment: that issue solved too:))  just for the people who will scrimmage the same problem as mine , here is the [cheatSheet](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) and if you want too see the list of available shortcut use ctrl+j.